# Carbon Design Systems React UI Shell component is not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to use the Carbon Design's [UI Shell](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/experimental/ui-shell/usage) component.
I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/carbondesign/up-running-with-carbon-react-in-less-than-5-minutes-25d43cca059e) to install all libraries, dependencies, etc.

Below is my code:

```
import {UIShell} from 'carbon-components-react';
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';



function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <p>
      Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
    <a
      className="App-link"
      href="https://reactjs.org"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener noreferrer"
    >
      Learn React
    </a>
    <UIShell>UIShell Placeholder</UIShell>

  </header>
 </div>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
 "Failed to compile: ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'UIShell' is not exported from 'carbon-components-react'."
```

According to the [repository](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-react/tree/master/src/components/UIShell), UIShell is a component of **carbon-components-react**. 
    Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `./node_modules/carbon-components-react/lib/index.js`, you will see that, although `UIShell` is defined in `.../lib/components/`, it's not exported.

So the question is actually... how can we access the UIShell components from the `carbon-components-react` component library when it's not exported?

I have found that that it's possible to import the `UIShell` component library explicitly:

```
import {...} from 'carbon-components-react/es/components/UIShell'
```

Or, if you are not using ESM, I think that you could `require` the components via the following:

```
require('carbon-components-react/lib/components/UIShell')
```

Comment: still doesn't work for me - I've used { ... } from 'carbon-..., I got an 'unexpected token' error. But when I am trying to import a specific component(for  example, { Header } from 'carbon...etc.), I got "./src/App.js
  Line 33:  'AriaLabelPropType' is not defined  no-undef". Line 33 is where I have the 'import' statement.

Comment: What is your exact import statement? Also, I don't think that 'UIShell' is a component in itself as you have specified in your question. If I remember correctly from looking at the documentation, there is the plan for an 'encapsulating' component. But for now you have to build it up with Header, SideNav, etc. This definitely works as I was able to create the UIShell that they have in their components examples docs

Comment: I tried **import {Header} from 'carbon-components-react/es/components/UIShell'** and **import {SideNav} from 'carbon-components-react/es/components/UIShell'**

Comment: I don't know then :/